Running async NATS functions synchronously
I want to wrap a python module so it can be used either directly via import or via RPC through NATS, as transparently as possible. The problem is that when using NATS, all functions are async and as module they are not, which makes the usage very different. So I wanted to wrap the async functions in asyncio.run(fn()) but I am facing all kinds of problems.
Here is a minimal server for testing:
from nats.aio.client import Client as NATS
import asyncio

nc = NATS()

async def connect():
    await nc.connect("nats://localhost:4222")

async def subscribe():
    async def callback(msg):
        await msg.respond(b"pong")
    await nc.subscribe("service", cb=callback)
    await asyncio.sleep(3600)

async def main():
    await connect()
    await subscribe()

asyncio.run(main())

(coroutines on the server side are ok)
and here is the problematic client:
from nats.aio.client import Client as NATS
import asyncio

nc = NATS()

async def connect():
    await nc.connect("nats://localhost:4222")

async def publish():
    await nc.publish("publish", b"hello world")

async def request():
   await nc.request("service", b"ping")

async def close():
    await nc.close()

#this works:
# async def main():
#     await connect()
#     await publish()
#     await request()
#     await close()
# asyncio.run(main())

# this does not work:
asyncio.run(connect()) # works
asyncio.run(publish()) # works
asyncio.run(request()) # times out
asyncio.run(close()) # Event loop is closed

This is a minimal example to show the problem. In my real world scenario, the client would look something like this:
RPC = True # cli arg or env variable or something
if RPC:
    from mylib_RPC import Service
else:
    from mylib import Service
service = Service()
print(service.add(5, 3))
print(service.sub(7, 2))

and all the async juggling should happen under the hood.
I am aware that asyncio.run() is supposed to be called only once but here it's said that multiple calls are fine.
Why does this not work? What can I do instead? My current idea is to create a thread running one event loop and then communicating with that thread from synchronous functions, but it feels a bit overkill.

Did you ever figure out a solution to this?

No, I just accepted that I am not going to have interchangeability :/
